# Make div ignore parent div which has margin set to 0 auto

Tags: html, css

How can I ignore the style of the parent div

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

I want to ignore this style for a div without nesting it outside of its parent. Is this possible in CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the child's margins. That will override the parent's css. CSS works in a hierarchical fashion where the most specific CSS is used ("closest" to the element for lack of a better term).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, only set a value for the div, example

```
.parent { margin: 0 auto; }
.other-Div { margin: 0; }
```