# Ignore margin of parent div that uses auto

Tags: css, html

I would like to have a div ignore the margin of its parent div as in such a case:
html:

```
    <div class="wrap">
        I'm annoying!
        <div class="myown"> I don't want to have that annoying guy's margin! </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
    .wrap {width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;} /* Do not change */
    .myown{margin: 0;}
```

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628644/make-div-ignore-parent-div-which-has-margin-set-to-0-auto) but it still doesn't work!
Here it is when ran: http://jsfiddle.net/KYbq3/2/
Under my circumstances I cannot change `.wrap` but only `.myown`.

Comment: Are you expecting the child div to stretch across the entire window while remaining inside of the parent div? Basically, what should the expected results look like?

Comment: I want the child div to be as if the parent div hadn't changed the margins at all. The answer bažmegakapa provided (but excluding the width) is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to "break out" of the container, then your only option seems to be `position: absolute;`. The problem with it is that it takes the element out of the natural flow.

```
.myown{ 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KYbq3/4/)

Comment: This works, but why would 'margin: 0' in the child not override the parent even though the position is set to absolute?

Comment: @Aaron You have nothing to override, it's a misconception. `margin` is never inherited by the children of an element. Every element is living in the box defined by it's parent (except absolutely positioned ones, and maybe a few other cases), that is why it seems like it has inherited the margin - but it has not.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the width of the parent warp, you can calculate the diference with the viewport

then divide the diference between 2 (left and right margin)
and use the value as a negative margin-left for your own element.

and if you want to ignore the right margin, you can assign the with to 100vw.

```html
<style>
    .wrap {width: 200px; margin: 0 auto;} /* Do not change */
    
    .myown {    
        margin-left: calc( (-100vw + 200px ) /2);
        width: 100vw;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrap">
    I'm annoying!
    <div class="myown"> I don't want to have that annoying guy's margin! </div>
</div>
```